# Android Firebase Service is not getting SharedPreferences value

Tags: android, firebase, service, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I am setting sharedPreferences value on my fragment (Kotlin) , then I would like to use this value on my FirebaseMessagingService (Java). When I set value and destroy app and open again, there isn't any problem on my fragment. I can see the set value. So I am sure that sharedPreferences value updated by my fragment. But when I try to use that value on FirebaseMessagingService, I am getting always default value.

Here how I am setting on kotlin class:

```
sharedPref = activity?.getSharedPreferences("com.xxx.xxx.xxx",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)!!

private fun sharedPrefWrite(boolean: Boolean){
    with (sharedPref?.edit()) {
        this!!.putBoolean("notf", boolean)
        apply()
    }
}
```

This working good.

And here is how I am getting this data on FirebaseMessagingService:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.xxx.xxx.xxx",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(preferences.getBoolean("notf",true))
    sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}
```

and always service sending notification.

And I didn't start this service on my activity, It is only under Application tag on Manifest.xml like that;

```
     <service android:name="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.newsFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Any suggestion about why I couldn't get this value ? Thanks

**EDIT:**

I just did couple debug and when application on resume (on foreground), firebase service getting value correctly.. But If application on background (onPause) or if application destroyed, service *can't* fetch correct data from SharedPreferences.

**EDIT 2**

I removed onMessageReceived function from my FirebaseMessagingService, and re-install that app to my device, and when App on destroyed, I got the notification even there is no 'onMessageReceived ' ...

**LAST EDIT**

Solution below

Comment: Try using commit() instead of apply().

Comment: @rmanalo still same

Comment: Did the saving and retrieving happens almost at the same time? From my experience, if you save a pref then immediately want to use it, you might not get the value you are expecting. I got a workaround for it but it won't work on your case because they're on separate classes.

Comment: @rmanalo no service calling after couple of seconds

Comment: Are you sure that the preference exists? getBoolean methods returns default value event when the preference does not exist. Try to use contains(String key) to understand if the preference exists

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi Yes I am sure because in fragment, I can see changing on value

Comment: @Ozan, sure but the call in the service may return a different value. Check it with contains within the service side

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi I just check and here is the result: When application on resume, service geting value correctly.. But If application on background (onPause) or if application destroyed, service can not fetch correct data from SharedPreferences.

Comment: @Ozan, this doesn't make much sense. SharedPreferences must retain data even when the application is killed, are you sure that there's not something that is clearing application data? You can see the amount of cached data from your app settings.

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi If something clean my data, it means I can't see changed value on my fragment too when I destroy and re-open app again..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188473/discussion-between-nicola-gallazzi-and-ozan).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem finally..

There are two types of messages in FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging):

Display Messages: These messages trigger the onMessageReceived() callback only when your app is in foreground

Data Messages: Theses messages trigger the onMessageReceived() callback even if your app is in foreground/background/killed

So I have to post Data message for my app. Normally it is done something like that;

```
POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Headers

```
Key: Content-Type, Value: application/json
Key: Authorization, Value: key=<your-server-key>
```

Body using topics

```
{
   "to": "/topics/my_topic",
   "data": {
    "my_custom_key": "my_custom_value",
    "my_custom_key2": true
    }
}
```

**BUT This no longer works (Error 401).. There will be Auth problem for this case beacuse FCM now using OAUTH 2**

So I read [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message) and according to documentation new way to post data message is;

```
POST: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_FIREBASEDB_ID/messages:send
```

Headers

```
Key: Content-Type, Value: application/json
```

Auth

```
Bearer YOUR_TOKEN
```

Body

```
{
   "message":{
    "topic" : "xxx",
    "data" : {
         "body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
         "title" : "FCM Message"
          }
      }
 }
```

In the url there is Database Id which you can find it on your firebase console. (Go project setttings)

And now lets take our token (It will valid only 1 hr):

First in the Firebase console, open **Settings > Service Accounts**.
Click **Generate New Private Key**, securely store the JSON file containing the key. Iwas  need this JSON file to authorize server requests manually. I downloaded it.

Then I create a node.js project and used this function to get my token;

```
var PROJECT_ID = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';
var HOST = 'fcm.googleapis.com';
var PATH = '/v1/projects/' + PROJECT_ID + '/messages:send';
var MESSAGING_SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging';
var SCOPES = [MESSAGING_SCOPE];

  router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
      getAccessToken().then(function(accessToken) {
        console.log("TOKEN: "+accessToken)
      })

    });

function getAccessToken() {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var key = require('./YOUR_DOWNLOADED_JSON_FILE.json');
    var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
        key.client_email,
        null,
        key.private_key,
        SCOPES,
        null
    );
    jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
        if (err) {
            reject(err);
            return;
        }
        resolve(tokens.access_token);
    });
});
}
```

Now I an use this token in my post request. Then I post my data message, and it is now handled by my apps *onMessageReceived* function.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, with not everything from Android api working correctly in my FirebaseMessagingService.

I figured this can have something to do with limitations of running background services from Oreo and higher, and FCM messages being of exception to those
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services

I guess you only got this problem on Android>=8, right?

So what I did now, is two pieces of code, for pre-Oreo and Oreo-and-newer respectively, running from my onMessageReceived

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        val body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            scheduleJobService(body);
        } else {
            runIntentService(body);
        }
}
```

then in runIntentService I just start an Intent service (I guess you know how do do that), but this can work only pre-Oreo, because of the mentioned limitations

on Android 8 and higher you would need to schedule a JobService or implement your own custom BroadcastReceiver...

I choose JobService, because it was easier for me, and I didn't mind waiting sometimes a bit for Android to schedule my Job, what I did is:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private fun scheduleNotificationJobService(body: String) {
    val serviceName = ComponentName(getPackageName(),
            NotificationJobService::class.java.name)

    val scheduler = getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler

    val notificationInfoBundle = PersistableBundle()
    notificationInfoBundle.putString(Constants.EXTRA_NOTIF_BODY, body)

    val builder = JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, serviceName)
            .setOverrideDeadline(0)
            .setExtras(notificationInfoBundle)
    val notificationInfo = builder.build()
    scheduler.schedule(notificationInfo)
}
```

then your JobService would kook like this:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
class NotificationJobService : JobService() {

    override fun onStopJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {}

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onStartJob(params: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        params?.extras?.let {
            val body = it.getString(Constants.EXTRA_NOTIF_BODY)
            val preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.xxx.xxx.xxx",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            if(preferences.getBoolean("notf",true)){
                sendNotification(body);
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

remember do declare it in AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <service android:name=".push.NotificationJobService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE">
    </service>
```

let me know pls if that works for you too :)
cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try it and let you know the results

Comment: It didn't work.. Actually, I removed onMessageReceived function from my FirebaseMessagingService, and of course I removed old app completely and then I install that app (there is no onMessageReceived function) and when App on destroyed, I got the notification even there is no 'onMessageReceived ' ...

Comment: I suspect in activity?.getSharedPreference(). Try replacing activity?. getSharedPreference() with applicationContext.getSharedPreferences ()??